# Is it possible to specify the caret position of JTextPane in terms of X and Y coordinates somehow?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, caret

JtextPane `setCaretPosition()` takes an int as the parameter, but I need to specify the caret position in terms of x and y pixel coordinates. Is there any way in which I can achieve this?

Edit:
I have replaced the previous SSCCE, with some original code, to show how the data comes in, as there are no problems when doc string is hard coded.
Code Snippet:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;


public class Mock extends JDialog{

    JFrame f = new JFrame("My mock ");
    JTextPane contentPlaceHolder = new JTextPane();
    StyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    String content = "This is line 1\n"+ 
                     "This is line 2\n" + 
                     "This is line 3\n"+ 
                     "This is line 4\n" + 
                     "This is line 5\n";

    int x, y;
    OutputStream out;
    InputStream in;

    KeyAdapter kl = new KeyAdapter()
    {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
            int c = e.getKeyChar();

            try
            {
                    out.write(c);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception occured in key Typed event:\n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
            e.consume();
        }

    };

     private void initGUI() throws BadLocationException{

         new RemoteConsumer().start();
         contentPlaceHolder.addKeyListener(kl);
         doc.insertString(0, content, null);
         contentPlaceHolder.setDocument(doc);
         f.getContentPane().add(contentPlaceHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         contentPlaceHolder.setVisible(true);
         pack();
         f.setSize(400, 300);
         f.setVisible(true);
         System.out.println("Should be visible");
         new RemoteConsumer().start();
     } 

     void startGUI()
        {
            Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        initGUI();
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            };

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);

        }    

        class RemoteConsumer extends Thread
        {
            char[][] lines = new char[y][];
            int posy = 0;
            int posx = 0;

            private void addText(byte[] data, int len) throws BadLocationException 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    char c = (char) (data[i] & 0xff);

                    /**
                     * based on the character, there will be   positioning of cursor based on posx, posy. 
                       I want to use this posx and posy as the coordinates for caret position
                     * after that, buffer is appended with newly arrived character
                     */

                    if (lines[posy] == null)
                    {
                        lines[posy] = new char[x];
                        for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
                            lines[posy][k] = ' ';
                    }

                    lines[posy][posx] = c;
                    posx++;
                }
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(x * y);


                for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 0)
                        sb.append('\n');

                    if (lines[i] != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(lines[i]);
                    }
                }                           
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), sb.toString(), null);
                contentPlaceHolder.setDocument(doc);            
            }

            /**
             * This is the entry point from which the data comes in
             * Now, it will give error, as no data has been sent by server
             */
            public void run()
            {
                byte[] buff = new byte[8192];

                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int len = in.read(buff);
                        if (len == -1)
                            return;
                        addText(buff, len);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error in reading value : " + e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException
        {

            Mock mk = new Mock();
            mk.startGUI();
        }
}
```

please note, hard coding the value of doc presents no problem. The problem only occurs when typed characters are displayed on the pane [the command for that is `out.write(character)`, where `out` is of type `OutputStream`] .

Comment: have to convert possition from model to view

Comment: @mKorbel Think you forgot the link :P

Comment: @mKorbel: model to view again takes a single int as position, and returns x, y coordinates.. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? As the caret positions are character based and if at all you are able to do that based on pixels your caret may land on a character not before or after.

Comment: @user123 right yes then this is proper possition for Caret in View, because Document can contains whitespaces chars, html, images, JComponents (for images, JComponents should be used JEditorPane) that aren't displayable in view,

Comment: Somehow, the caret doesn't automatically show up at the right position.The JTextPane isn't hardcoded, it is populated with a string buffer.

Comment: @user123 (btw again the same song about) for better help sooner SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for Document, because all commenters in your last question can to answering your questions without any special effort

Comment: @mKorbel , but it is doing the opposite work from my required way.I need to give x and y coordinates and get a single value..

Comment: @mKorbel: Alright, I am posting SSCCE, but the point is: if I place hard coded values, then the caret works fine, my problem occurs when I am typing in the pane.

Comment: 1. in isn't initialized, 2. use DocumentFilter (for event inside Document) or DOcumentListener (for Even outside of current JTextComponent that firing an Event) 22 don't to use KeyListener for JTextComponents, otherwise events from Keylistener should be wrapped into invokeLater, 3. then Char is inserted twice, that correct, 4. for another suggestion I miss goal, Caret is correctly moved, by using Swing Timer, incl. Caret and Selection, 5. Caret, Selection, Highlighter doesn't works in the case that updates to already Swing GUI is out of EDT

Answer (score 0):

There is a `viewToModel` method in `JTextComponent`, which accepts a `Point` and returns an `int` position in the `Document`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#viewToModel(java.awt.Point)

It's OK for JTextPane, as it extends JEditorPane, which extends JTextComponent.